# Android:TextView Movement in Vertical direction attached with button click listener

Tags: java, android, textview

How to move textview in vertical direction when I tap on button?

```
msgtxt.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility") public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                drag(event, v);
                return false;
            }
        });


    public void drag(MotionEvent event, View v)
    {

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();

        switch(event.getAction())
        {
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
           {
               params.topMargin = (int)event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
             params.leftMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);

             v.setLayoutParams(params);
             break;
           }


        }
        }
```

As you can see above code, I can move the textview using onTouchListener but here the  text in the textview is also moving that I don't want. I am sharing an image where I have mentioned my requirement.

[image: Please check my requirement in the image]